# MySQL pconnect erroring for single user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue where a single user is intermittently receiving the following error when attempting to connect to a website using a MySQL database:

```
Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Can't connect to local MySQL     server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/wind/public_html/db.php on line 13
```

The one user is connecting from the same computer each time. She receives it approximately once per day. The other 40+ daily users are not receiving it at all, including from within the same network. Any thoughts? My conjecture is that this should affect everyone equally - but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If she receive too many connections,
change the max allowed connections to mysql from mysql.ini file

Comment: How would I check how many connections she's making?

Is the problem that she's making too many connections through pconnect? Looking into this, I've been reading that pconnect isn't a good solution (quiet frankly, I don't recall why I'm even using it). Any suggestions on alternatives? I'd like it to not affect most of my code if possible.